# Is it possible to publish content from our pc to insta using graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

What I mean is, can we post content through container without making them publically available in a server(URL)?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to with "containers". Guide for IG publishing API is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: I mean the endpoints, /media and /media_publish. The posting has two steps one is to provide the image url to the /media endpoint to make it into a media container. Then passing this to the /media_publish endpoint to post on the instagram account. So I am asking if there is a one step way like to post directly as an image from my pc to the account without the image being in a public server and using its url. I only saw the two step process in graph api docs.

Comment: Don't see anything else there either, so I would assume there is no other way.